# VirtualHost em arquivo separado - Apache compilado

Tags: apache

Devido há uma grande quantidade de `VirtualHosts` que possuo, o arquivo em `/etc/apche247/conf/extra/httdp-vhost.conf` fica extenso e desorganizado.

Sei algumas maneiras de criar o `VirtualHost` dinâmico, porém na instalação automática do Apache (apt-get/yum/pacman install), utilizando a pasta `sites-enabled`.

Porém, com o Apache compilado, tais pastas não existem, e não sei uma maneira dinâmica (sem a necessidade de incluir o arquivo no **httpd.conf**), de fazer isso.

Comment: não é criar a pasta sites-enabled e no final do arquivo apache2.conf colocar Include sites-enabled/ ?

Comment: @DanielLemes pra ser sincero não sei Daniel. Não testei desta maneira ainda.

Comment: é a mesma coisa que te responderam ali embaixo, acho que é só isso sim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta você criar essa pasta você mesmo! Eu também estava usando uma instalação do Apache que não usava o `sites-enabled`, então vi em uma que usava como era feito e fiz igual. É uma simples questão de criar a pasta e adicionar a seguinte linha no `httpd.conf`:

```
Include /caminho/para/o/apache/conf/sites-enabled/
```

Então você poderá usar o `sites-enabled` normalmente (i.e. um arquivo por Virtual Host). Eu sugiro também (se estiver numa plataforma com suporte a links simbólicos) criar uma pasta `sites-available`, criar os arquivos lá e somente "linkar" aqueles que estão ativos no `sites-enabled` (de modo a poder rapidamente tirar e colocar sites no ar).

Comment: Vou testar aqui...

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado.